# I am stuck in Laravel Livewire in which I am using multiple select2 and it is a wizard form

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, jquery-select2, laravel-livewire

I have a wizard in laravel livwire with 4 steps.
in the first step I have select box of select2 for multiple selection, everything works fine but when I go to step 2 and return back, the problems comes
Select2 distorts and loose it's styling
Selectbox does not contain it's selected values

I am new to livwire so do not enough about it.

Here is my blade component
I don't exactly know what is the purpose of wire:ignore but I used it from internet.

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 mb-10">
    <x-label for="vehicle_groups" class="required">Vehicle Groups</x-label>
    <div wire:ignore>
       <x-select-two class="form-select-solid"  id="vehicle_groups" multiple>
          <option value=""></option>
          @foreach($vehicleGroups as $vehicleGroup)
             <option value="{{ $vehicleGroup->id }}">{{ $vehicleGroup->group_name }}</option>
          @endforeach
       </x-select-two>
    </div>
    @error('vehicle_groups')
       <x-error>{{ $message }}</x-error>
    @enderror
</div>
```

```
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("livewire:load", () => {
            $('#vehicle_groups').select2().on('change', function (e) {
                var data = $('#vehicle_groups').select2("val");
                @this.set('vehicle_groups', data);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

here is my livewire component

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Vgroup;
use Livewire\Component;

class Vehicle extends Component
{
    public $currentPage = 1;
    public $type, $vehicle_groups;


    public function mount()
    {

    }
    public function render()
    {
        $vehicleGroups = Vgroup::get(['id', 'group_name']);
        return view('admin.livewire.vehicle', compact('vehicleGroups'));
    }

    public function gotToNextPage()
    {
        if ($this->currentPage === 1) {
            $this->validate([
                'type' => ['required'],
                'vehicle_groups' => ['required']
            ]);

        } elseif ($this->currentPage === 2) {

        } else {

        }
        $this->currentPage++;
    }

    public function gotToPreviousPage()
    {
        $this->currentPage--;
    }


    public function submitForm()
    {
        $this->currentPage = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to be a bug. I am too stuck in this did not find any solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

**wire:ignore** you will use it, if you don't want to rerender a part of your code, for example imagine you have a js code, and when using it with livewire it can not work well, because livewire makes requests every time and the js code can't do it's job, now, you have to know that select2, creates it's own DOM and livewire keeps making requests(so you can see it's not a good combination), for that reason you need to add wire:ignore(to ignore select2).

So the problem that the styles doesn't render again, you could try adding the select 2 inside a DOMContentLoaded event:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        $('#vehicle_groups').select2();
})
```

like this, the styles will be added when the page is loaded

on the other side, to get the data, you could try and add the ready event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#vehicle_groups').select2("val");
})
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#vehicle_groups').select2();
    $('#vehicle_groups').val();
})
```

I see that you are using an event **"livewire:load"**, in my case this event didn't work for me(in the inspector it throw me an error that the event didn't exist), you could try and use a hook instead of **"livewire:load"**

```
Livewire.hook('message.processed', (message, component) => {

    })
```

this event will be called when all the requests of livewire are finished

https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/lifecycle-hooks

here is the link to the documentation if you want to check it

And last i want to comment something, i saw that you are using $vehicleGroup (i guess it's an array), you are getting the data on the view, all okei there, however you using the array on select 2, to overrite the data, is that what you want to do?**(@this.set('vehicle_groups', data))**

you could use the attribute wire:model(if you don't need to make requests every time in that select better use wire:model.defer, like this the only request that is going to make is when it's submited), to call a variable on livewire and store the value of the select

```
<x-select-two class="form-select-solid" wire:model="vehicle_variable"  id="vehicle_groups" multiple>
          <option value=""></option>
          @foreach($vehicleGroups as $vehicleGroup)
             <option value="{{ $vehicleGroup->id }}">
                 {{$vehicleGroup->group_name }}
             </option>
          @endforeach
       </x-select-two>
```

**wire:model="vehicle_variable"**

now on livewire:

**public $vehicle_variable**

and on select2:

**@this.set('vehicle_variable', data)**

now you have the value on a variable and not an array(if it's an array)

to check if the data exists, you could use the debugger of laravel "ddd()" inside the function mount (the mount function, will be called when the page is being loaded):

```
public function mount()
{
    ddd($vehicle_variable);
}
```

if it's not null, then select2 should work however, if the value is null you need to check your livewire

if you have any question, just ask and i will try to answer!